# Как избавиться от google-analytics?

Tags: html, javascript

До меня на сайте кто-то ставил эту статистику. 
Я хочу ее убрать с корнями. Удалил сайт с панели в гугле. Но где-то в коде он все равно остался. 
Как его можно найти?

В файле frame.html нашел такой код:

```
<body {$GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SET_TRANS}{if $main_body_style} {$main_body_style}{/if}{if $PAGE_VIEW eq 'printable'} style="background-color:#FFFFFF;background-image:none;"{/if}{if $page_not_found404} class="body-page-404"{/if}>
<!--  BODY -->
{if $main_body_tpl}{include file=$main_body_tpl}{else}
{if $page_not_found404}{include file="404.html"}{else}{include file="index.html"}{/if}
{/if}
{if !$smarty.get.productwidget && !$productwidget &&!$printable_version && $show_powered_by }
<div id="powered_by">
{if $show_powered_by_link}
    {lbl_powered_by}
{else}
    {lbl_powered_by_text}
{/if}
</div>{/if}

<!--  END -->
{if !$page_not_found404 &&!$printable_version}
{$GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE}
{/if}
```

удалил `{$GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SET_TRANS}` и `{$GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CODE`. Но ничего не изменилось

Сайт: oooenergy.ru

Comment: @Радик Камалов скорее всего вы не удалили скомпилированный файл, либо кеш.

Comment: не понял, какой скомпилированный файл?

Comment: @Радик Камалов шаблонизатор smarty сначала компилирует ваш шаблон в исполняемый файл, который находится в compileDir. Так вот, скомпилированный файл нужно удалить, чтобы скомпилировался новый. И кеш почистить.

Answer (score 1):

Написали бы сразу сайт на webasyst и ответ был бы скорее :)
В админке - Магазин - Инструменты - Google Analytics. А то, что удалили лучше верните назад - вдруг потом пригодится.

Comment: Оттуда я уже удалил. В том то и проблема, что откуда-то он еще подгружается. Это видно в файрфоксе при загрузке страницы: Передача данных с google analytics

Comment: либо кеш, его можно в oooenergy.ru/installer/ удалить, либо он все-таки в теме прописан - дизайн- темы - текущая - редактировать